# Mutiple client webrequests - object structure approach needed (edited)

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, timer

I'm seeking for a approach for the following problem: I'm doing gps tracking. The data is being provided over http post requests by a gps data provider. The application should handle about one hundred trackings and poll each position max every second.

My approach so far: Out of a collection every object sets off async web requests triggered by a timer. The async request fails, while the sync request is successful. Needs to be fixed or checked (different problem) Another approach would be: every trace object sets off a backgroundworker thread with a sync httprequest and on completion it starts the next request.

What approach would you choose?

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question you just posted?

Comment: No, but I admit they sound similar. It's a different software project. The other one was a simple Get request to one uri and i faced trouble with the connection and not completely received files. This time I'm interested in how to manage multiple client HTTPpost request internally, regarding the object structure. It's a GPS tracking service I want to send requests to, and I'm tracking nearly 100 devices. The service returns a string.

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information to it. Otherwise, your question may be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a timer approach, where I get background working behaviour from. The timer helps me set pauses between pollings easily.

Answer (score 0):

We need more data to answer this question. First, you said that Async download is failing. How exactly is it failing? What exceptions are you getting?